# How to export the admin theme settings on Drupal 7 and push it to the server with GIT?

Tags: drupal-7, themes, settings

On the admin environment of `Drupal 7`, I have changed the Administration theme by going to the `Appearance` page. Under section `ADMINISTRATION THEME`, I have selected a theme from the dropdown list and clicked on `Save configuration`.

The selected theme is applied. This is on my `localhost`. I would like to export this `settings` or `configuration` and push it to my git repository to apply this theme settings or configuration on my testing server. How can I export this theme settings on Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

The best option here would be to install the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module. You can then configure it to export all of your site-wide (including theme) settings and also have the added benefit of 'reverting' to the exported settings if anything were to change.

Give it a try and drop a comment if you get stuck.

Comment: Which feature name and component are for the administration theme settings? I see all features by running drush fl and see all feature components by running drush features-components.